# android distribution filter based on processor or RAM

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, marmalade

I'm developing a new game, which has 2 sets of images (Low-resolution and hi-res).
I planned to use low-resolution images in devices with small RAM and/or low processing power.

I've taken care of scaling and tested it on XPeria ARC with low-resolution images and Nexus5 with hi-resolution images. In both devices game works fine.

when I've uploaded it to Google Play Store, I want to upload 2 separate apks with low-res and hi-res images.

Is there anyway I can specify/filter apks to be available based on RAM/Processor

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have `drawable-*` folders to handle that?

Comment: there are not ram/cpu filters for the play store

Comment: You can't filter with the amount of RAM and the only filter for the CPU is the cpu architecture arm or x86 or mips. But you have (ldpi mdpi hdpi ...) Isn't that enough?

Comment: @shkschneider yes, drawable-* can be used but it'll result in apk ,with same images with multiple resolution, with more size than required

Comment: @hegazy devices with same resolution has different processing powers, during testing some devices could load hi-resolution images and some devices with same screen resolution crashed while loading hi-resolution images.

Comment: As @tyczj said, there is no "minimal configuration requirements" on Google Play regardin RAM/CPU power. Include all resources in the APK (`drawable-*` mechanism) or try to split your resources in separate APKs, run a benchmark and download them as *extension APKs*.... maybe.